# TinyMce not behaving in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, tinymce

I have TinyMce version 3.4.8 and IE9.

When I'm typing text in the tinymce editor, it inserts empty spaces between the letters.
This is a problem because I'm later using the entered values in the tinymce to search in a database. So, in IE9 I always get no results because it's searching with the empty spaces.

What can be the problem? I thought maybe encoding problem or compatibility between IE9 and tinymce, but I can't find anything about that on Google.

Comment: @Thariama Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: +1 hmm, i am not sure, but tinymce version 3.4.8 is not very up-to-date. did you consider updating your tinymce already?